# Xcode Auto Layout Constraints not working (using storyboard)

Tags: ios, layout, uibutton, autolayout

I have been using Auto Layout programaticaly, but now I want to see what the storyboard feature in Xcode is all about. I think I have created my constraints for the first button (the button on the bottom left) correctly:

[image: INTERFACE BUILDER]

I don't seem to have any conflicting or ambiguous constraints, however when I run the app on my phone to test, it looks like this:

[image: PHONE SCREENSHOT]

As you can see, the button is in the top left...and no matter what constraints I try to use, the button always sticks to the top left. I want it to be in the bottom left hand corner.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**UPDATE**

I've tried the suggestions and neither have worked...here is how I have it setup now - I had to do left:-16 top:0 right:-16 bottom:0 to get the mapView constraints to work. For the button I used the insets option (as posted in an answer) and did bottom:0, left:0 - so as to pin it to the bottom left corner (only two constraints neccessary?):

[image: UPDATED]

Comment: Pin the button bottom to the bottom of the mapViews parent view

Comment: just add the leading space and bottom space to zero to your button it will stick button to bottom left

Comment: you have to give it a leading and top/bottom constraint to the superview

Comment: so it should only need 2 restraints? dont need width and height?

Comment: also - do i need `[self.view addSubview:]` to add the button to the layout or is there an option to do that in the storyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Clear all contrains and:

1) pin MapView: 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 from Super View
2) pin button: 0(left) - 0 (bottom) from MapView
3) add width and heigth contraint

It should works

Comment: when i do as you suggest the left and bottom restraints end up being ambiguous...

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot, the mapView seems to be some sort of custom class not the `MKMapView` you can drag from the Interface Builder.

I just tried it and if you would have the normal `MKMapView`, you would not be able to add subviews to the map. This is the setup I tried and all works as it is supposed to.

[image: Map view with button]

My suggestion would be to move the buttons not the same level as the mapView (so that they have the same `superView`). Then you add your constraints and all should work just fine.

I think that the mapView has it's own way of handling subviews so maybe it just clears the constraints you add in the storyboard.

Let me know how it went! Good luck